# Как уменьшить данный контейнер в таблице для email письма?

Tags: html, css, email

Всячески пытался уменьшить размер контейнера, но ячейка просто не уменьшается. Т.е. бордеры должны быть такие же как и фотка. Буду очень благодарен за пинок, спасибо!

```html
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" style="mso-table-lspace:0pt;mso-table-rspace:0pt;border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0px;border-left:1px solid #292929;border-right:1px solid #292929;border-top:1px solid #292929;border-bottom:1px solid #292929;background-position:center top;">
  <tr style="border-collapse:collapse;">
    <td align="center" class="es-m-txt-c" style="padding:0;Margin:0;padding-top:30px;">
      <p style="Margin:0;-webkit-text-size-adjust:none;-ms-text-size-adjust:none;mso-line-height-rule:exactly;font-size:15px;font-family:'open sans', 'helvetica neue', helvetica, arial, sans-serif;line-height:23px;color:#333333;">Введите этот код в корзине</p>
      <p style="Margin:0;-webkit-text-size-adjust:none;-ms-text-size-adjust:none;mso-line-height-rule:exactly;font-size:15px;font-family:'open sans', 'helvetica neue', helvetica, arial, sans-serif;line-height:23px;color:#333333;">перед оформлением</p>
      <p style="Margin:0;-webkit-text-size-adjust:none;-ms-text-size-adjust:none;mso-line-height-rule:exactly;font-size:15px;font-family:'open sans', 'helvetica neue', helvetica, arial, sans-serif;line-height:23px;color:#333333;">заказаfourseasonsshop.ru</p>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr style="border-collapse:collapse;">
    <td align="center" style="Margin:0;padding-bottom:15px;padding-left:15px;padding-right:15px;padding-top:25px;">
      <p style="Margin:0;-webkit-text-size-adjust:none;-ms-text-size-adjust:none;mso-line-height-rule:exactly;font-size:15px;font-family:'open sans', 'helvetica neue', helvetica, arial, sans-serif;line-height:23px;color:#333333;">Код для скидки 15%:</p>
      <h4 id="code" style="Margin:0;line-height:22px;mso-line-height-rule:exactly;font-family:'open sans', 'helvetica neue', helvetica, arial, sans-serif;font-size:18px;">GG-FF-DD</h4>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr style="border-collapse:collapse;">
    <td align="center" bgcolor="transparent" style="Margin:0;padding-top:10px;padding-left:10px;padding-right:10px;padding-bottom:40px;"> <span class="es-button-border" style="border-style:solid;border-color:transparent;background:#292929;border-width:0px;display:inline-block;border-radius:0px;width:auto;"> <a href="" class="es-button" target="_blank" style="mso-style-priority:100 !important;text-decoration:none;-webkit-text-size-adjust:none;-ms-text-size-adjust:none;mso-line-height-rule:exactly;font-family:'open sans', 'helvetica neue', helvetica, arial, sans-serif;font-size:12px;color:#FFFFFF;border-style:solid;border-color:#292929;border-width:15px 40px;display:inline-block;background:#292929;border-radius:0px;font-weight:normal;font-style:normal;line-height:14px;width:auto;text-align:center;">Перейти на сайт</a> </span>      </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

[image: рамки]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте поставить стили для таблицы не 100% а фиксированные, например 400px и margin: auto

Насколько я помню любое письмо на почту нужно верстать исходя что его размер по ширине равен 600px